# Confused about how Buffer encodes base64 in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8

I'm using Buffer in node.js to decode base64. I took a peek under the hood to see how Buffer stores raw byte data, and I am utterly confused as to how it works. For example, if I want to UTF-8 encode the string "©" using Buffer, like so: `Buffer("©", "utf-8").toJSON()`, I get the expected `[194, 169]` byte array. `Buffer("©", "ucs2").toJSON()` produces [169, 0], again, the expected byte representation. Now, I would expect `Buffer("Man", "base64").toJSON()` to be `[84, 87, 70, 117]`, which corresponds to the ascii bytes of the string "TWFu", the base64 encoded equivalent of "Man." However, I instead get `[49, 169]`. This seems incongruous with the way Buffer works in the previous two cases. Does anyone know why? Any help that can shed light on this much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The encoding you pass in tells the `Buffer` object that the byte sequence you also gave it *uses that encoding*. So: `Buffer("Man","utf8")` means "Create a buffer with the input "Man", and decode that input for internal storage as if the bytes are utf8 encoded". No problem there: it was, so it'll do the right thing:

```
> Buffer("Man", "utf8").toString() // note: no dash. The API docs tell us it's just "utf8".
'Man'
```

Now, if we claim that string "Man" is ucs2 encoded, we *don't* get just "Man", we get this:

```
> Buffer("Man", "ucs2").toString()
'M\u0000a\u0000n\u0000'
```

And if we try `Buffer("Man", "base64")` we're telling the Buffer that the string "Man" is base64 encoded, so it'll try to decode it before storing it, which means it'll first perform the equivalent of `atob(input)`, which turns "Man" into `1©`, and then the Buffer stores those two bytes.

```
> Buffer("Man", "base64").toString()
'1©'
```

Based on that, try `Buffer("TWFu","base64")`, and see if you understand why it returns what it does.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I may have an assumption that is incorrect---all strings in Node.js are encoded in ucs2. I know that is the case for most browser javascript implementations. I assumed that Buffer would take the raw bytes in ucs2 encoding, and map them to code points, and then to raw bytes of an encoding of your choice.

Comment: No worries. And to be fair, [the Buffer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_str_encoding) sure could be more explicit about this. They're kind of not.